# Converting a html/xhtml file with css to pdf/epub without loosing any of the styling

Tags: python, html, css, node.js, pdf

I have a somewhat complicated html file and some css styling for it, for example I need to use `display: flex` and I have some custom fonts, font sizes and font styles.

All of this styling stuff is done with css classes.

Can I convert this html/xhtml file to a pdf/epub file with the same formatting? I would prefer a python/node package or a command line tool.

Comment: Yes, to PDF at least. Unfortunately EPUB does not strictly define what CSS, or really HTML, is supported, it just depends on the particular viewers implementation. Are you looking to generate BOTH PDF and EPUB? If not, which do you prefer? and why? Finally, if EPUB output is important for you, are you looking for fixed, or reflowable, layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use CSS2 styles for pdf/epub

Comment: PDF doesn't support any CSS, except very tiny amount in some annotation types.